# How does the non executeable exploit work?

Tags: exploit

Hello the question is how works non executable exploit's, when i say non executable i mean those who don't have the file extension .exe, like word exploits .doc or other. How did they make some executable action if they are not compiled?

Comment: This question would be more popular over at security.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 2):

That varies from exploit to exploit.

While .doc isn't an executable format it does contain interpreted vba code which is generally where the malicious content was hidden.  When you opened the document there would be an onOpen event or some such fired which would execute the malicious payload.  Hence why most office installations have macro's disabled by default these days, far too much scope for abuse.

There are also plenty of things that will run on your system without being a .exe for example [.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file), [.vbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vbs), [.hta](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/hta)

Then there are formats which have no normal executable content but can be attacked in other ways, usually taking advantage of poorly written routines to load the files which can allow things like [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Comment: thnx for replay, but is that mean than when we disable all macros and other stuf's like that from are default setting's that exploit do not work?

Comment: It blocks one avenue of attack, sadly there are some very clever people out there who are constantly coming up with innovative new ways to attack systems.  There's a huge amount of information on security issues available online, you're best defence is still an uptodate virus scanner which automatically updates its definitions.  That said its something of an arms race between blackhats and av companies

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to exploit bugs in the code that handles those files. Often this will be a 'buffer overflow'. Perhaps the code is expecting a header of 100 bytes, but the malicious file has 120 bytes. That causes the program to overwrite some other data in its memory, and if you can smash the 'stack' with your extra bytes it's possible to redirect the processor to a 'payload' code embedded in your file.

google "buffer overflow exploit" for more.